# How to make two posts with different contents in GrailsIntegrationTesting

Tags: testing, grails, controller, integration

I'm testing a controller, and I cannot make two posts with different contents.
Follows an example, in which I execute a post to the cardController, with some data (post1, with json1). Then, I execute another post, with different data (post2 with json2). But I cannot make the second post succesfully, because I've seen (debuggin the application), that the json in the request, is json1 again, and not josn2. So, how can I make two different posts in the same test?

```
void testSomething(){

    def json1 = [number: "345678000000007", exp_month: 5, exp_year: 2012] as JSON
    def strJson1 = json1 as String

    cardController.request.contentType = "text/json"
    cardController.request.content = strJson1.getBytes()
    def post1 = cardController.post()

    def json2 = [number: "345678000000009", exp_month: 5, exp_year: 2013] as JSON
    def strJson2 = json2 as String

    cardController.request.contentType = "text/json"
    cardController.request.content = strJson2.getBytes()
    def post2 = cardController.post()
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because you're passing in the strJson1.getBytes() on the second post?

Comment: Yep, ataylor is right. Too simple to give an actual answer. :)  I hate it when I do stuff like that.

Comment: Just edit your question if you want to provide more information.

Comment: I have problems with this answer GrailsMockHttpServletRequest does not has any of these methods. Can you provide additional information about your context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, I could with reset(), removeAllParameters(), and clearAttributes().
Below is the example:

```
void testSomething(){

    def json1 = [number: "345678000000007", exp_month: 5, exp_year: 2012] as JSON
    def strJson1 = json1 as String

    cardController.request.contentType = "text/json"
    cardController.request.content = strJson1.getBytes()
    def post1 = cardController.post()


    cardController.response.reset()    
    cardController.request.reset()
    cardController.request.removeAllParameters()
    cardController.request.clearAttributes()

    def json2 = [number: "345678000000009", exp_month: 5, exp_year: 2013] as JSON
    def strJson2 = json2 as String

    cardController.request.contentType = "text/json"
    cardController.request.content = strJson2.getBytes()
    def post2 = cardController.post()
}
```

Comment: I am searching for the same although i get No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletRequest.reset() when trying this (?!)

Comment: In grails 2.4.x request.reset() does not exist.  However response.reset() does and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `cardController.response.reset()` after `def post1 = cardController.post()`. It's not expected that you'll make two requests per test method, so you need to do some cleanup.