# How to make multiple requests with different data in Grails Integration tests

Tags: testing, grails, integration, spock

I'm writing a Grails 2.2.1 integration test using the Spock plugin, in which I am trying to post two sets of data to the same controller endpoint:

```
when: "The user adds this product to the inventory"
def postData = [productId: 123]
controller.request.JSON = postData
controller.addToInventory()

and: "Then they add another"
def secondPostData = [productId: 456]
controller.request.JSON = secondPostData
controller.addToInventory()

then: "The size of the inventory should be 2"
new JSONObject( controller.response.contentAsString ).inventorySize == 2
```

The problem I am seeing is that the same JSON is submitted to addToInventory() for both requests.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344213/how-to-make-two-posts-with-different-contents-in-grailsintegrationtesting) suggests calling controller.request.reset(), but this did not work (No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletRequest.reset()).

Is what I am attempting possible?

Comment: One important thing, to note is the use of controller.request.JSON to pass data to the post method! It was really hard to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Where:" can be used to perform data driven testing in spock testing framework. Try, using the following example:

```
when: "The user adds this product to the inventory"

controller.params.JSON = [productId:productId]
controller.addToInventory()

then: "The size of the inventory should be 2"
new JSONObject( controller.response.contentAsString ).inventorySize == 2

where:

ID|productId
1|123
2|456
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks Anuj, I have refactored the test to look like your example above. There was also a problem with how I was assigning parameters to the request, so the line `controller.request.JSON = [productId:productId]` is now `controller.params.JSON = [productId:productId]`.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually another way.  Insert:

```
GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest()
```

at the start of your second test.  This will effectively create a new ServletContext, a new MockHttpServletRequest, a new MockHttpServletResponse, and then bind all three into the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

While Anuj us correct that `where` clauses should be used to keep tests clean, there are times when a test needs to run more than one request.  In my case I wanted to test that when it recieved 2 repeat POSTS, the 2nd one was rejected correctly.

I found that resetting the response did what I needed:

```
controller.response.reset()
```

To clear out the response.