# How to call call request.JSON multiple times in Grails unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock, grails-4

I am upgrading my application from Grails `2.5.6` to Grails `4.0.3`. Now I have lots of unit tests failed because I am calling controller methods with `request.JSON` multiple times in a single test. Those unit tests worked fine in old Grails `2.5.6`.

To demonstrate the problem, I have a controller with the following method:

```java
class TestController {
    def testJson(){
        def json = request.JSON
        render(contentType:'application/json', text:json.toString(), encoding: "UTF-8")
    }
}
```

And I have a unit test like this:

```java
class TestControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<TestController> {

    void "test json"(){
        when:
        request.json = [
                a:1, b:2, c:3
        ]
        controller.testJson()

        then:
        response.json.a == 1
        response.json.b == 2
        response.json.c == 3

        when:
        response.reset()
        request.json = [
                a:10, b:20, c:30
        ]
        controller.testJson()

        then:
        response.json.a == 10 // <-- test failed here
        response.json.b == 20
        response.json.c == 30
    }

}
```

The test will fail with the following error

```
response.json.a == 10
|        |    | |
|        |    1 false
|        [a:1, b:2, c:3]
```

The question is: how can I **reset** the state of the `request`? or why I cannot set new value to `request.json`?

Updated:
Please check this demo project: https://github.com/jaguar1975cn/grails403test

Comment: Try solutions mentioned in the post -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762871/how-to-make-multiple-requests-with-different-data-in-grails-integration-tests

Comment: @MKB, I understand you are suggesting to use `where` to work around it. I knew it will work, because if we use `where`, it actually executes those requests separately. But I have thousands of tests need to be refactored,  it will be a huge work.

Comment: Did you also notice in the other answer that there was a comment mentioning to use `controller.params.JSON` instead of `controller.request.JSON`?

Comment: @kriegaex thanks, `controller.params.JSON` doesn't work either. Same result.

Comment: What about `controller.response.reset()`? Otherwise maybe sharing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would be nice. I know some Spock, but zero Grails. An MCVE would be the only way for me to inspect this for you.

Comment: @kriegaex, `response.reset()` and `controller.response.reset()` are basically the same thing. So it makes no difference.

Comment: @kriegaex I updated the question. A demo project has been added. Thanks.